# How to serve static files from submodules in Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, static-files

I'm writing a Flask application divided into modules, with each module residing in a separate folder that includes 'templates' and 'static' folders.

In each module, I'm passing a global variable 'custom_js' to the template:

```
module_bp = Blueprint('module', __name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='static')

# pass custom js files to the base template
@module_bp.context_processor
def custom_js_context():
    return {'custom_js': ['some_file.js']}
```

I include these JavaScript files in the main template base.html like this:

```
{% if custom_js %}
    {% for js_file in custom_js %}
        <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/' + js_file) }}"></script>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

The code above results in adding  to base.html. The physical file is located at /module/static/js/some_file.js, but accessing http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/js/some_file.js results in a 404 error.

How can I correctly serve these JavaScript files from the modules?

---

One idea is to modify the blueprint to:

```
module_bp = Blueprint('module', 
                         __name__, 
                         template_folder='templates', 
                         static_folder='static',
                         static_url_path='/module/static'
                         )
```

and serving the files to the template like this:

```
@module_bp.context_processor
def custom_js_context():
    custom_js_files = ['some_file.js']
    custom_js_with_prefix = ['/module/static/js' + filename for filename in custom_js_files]
    return {'custom_js': custom_js_with_prefix}
```

with updated base.html loop

```
{% if custom_js %}
    {% for js_file in custom_js %}
        <script src="{{ js_file) }}"></script>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

However, I'm not sure to what extent this is the correct approach.

Comment: I wonder if you could use "url_for" in the context processor "custom_js_context". Within the controller Flask should know the blueprint's own path.

Comment: Sure, I can  write

`custom_js_with_prefix = [url_for(f'{module_bp.name}.static', filename='js/' + filename) for filename in custom_js_files]`

but stil not sure is it right path to solve my problem. Shouldn't the static files be served in an easier way, even if we choose a modular version of my project structure?

Comment: I was hoping that `url_for("static", filename= ...` would do as you are within the blueprint. A nuance but it would mean that the blueprint's own static path is being used automatically at least. Sorry, I should be more specific:

Comment: I was thinking something like `return {'custom_js': [url_for('static', 'js/' + filename)] in the context processor.

Comment: no, that would not work. Here it is explained: [https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/blueprints/#static-files](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/blueprints/#static-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solve this (whether that's the ordinary way with Flask, I can't tell):

```py
    _controller_name_ = "bugsandfeatures"
    _url_prefix_ = '/' + _controller_name_

    bp = Blueprint("bugsandfeatues", __name__,
                   template_folder='templates',
                   static_folder="static",
                   url_prefix=_url_prefix_)
```

Note the url_prefix, which makes sure that the blueprint actually serves static files from its own path (see [https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/blueprints/#static-files][1]).

Now you can:

```
    @bp.context_processor
    def custom_js_context():
        return {'custom_js': url_for('.static', filename='my_file.js')}
```

note that "." in front of static. It makes sure the endpoint is resolved by the current blueprint.
And when you pick the variable up in the template, you get ''/bugsandfeatures/static/my_file.js''.
[1]: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/blueprints/#static-files